# Создать только блок схему для задачи (python)

Tags: python, блок-схема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создать блок схему для задачи, начало блок схемы я представляю, а вот как оформляется нахождение наименьшего элемента, произведение и обмен местами столбцов?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.